# How can I get the user information using Spring Security with LDAP

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap

Im using Spring 3.1.1 with Spring Security 3.2.0 with LDAP authencitation.
I have gotten it to a point that works fine and I can log in using my LDAP username and password, I can even display the username with this

```
<security:authentication property="principal.username" />, is currently logged in.
```

I want to know how, if at all possible, can I get the first name, surname, email address or other information like that stored in my LDAP credentials.

I've tried `property="credentials"` but this returns null...

PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own UserDetailsContextMapper and load  LDAP user properties into the UserDetails object

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-custom-user-details

Comment: This link gives me a 404 :( is there an updated copy somewhere?

Comment: Try this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/ldap.html#ldap-custom-user-details

Answer (score 2):

This is eerily similar to my question a few days ago:

[How do I use a custom authorities populator with Spring Security and the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113115/how-do-i-use-a-custom-authorities-populator-with-spring-security-and-the-actived)

If you're not using Active Directory, you can simply extend the `LdapAuthenticationProvider` class and override the `loadUserAuthorities` method, in which you can capture the relevant user information based on the LDAP attributes for the user:

```
String firstName = userData.getStringAttribute("givenName");
String lastName = userData.getStringAttribute("sn");

//etc.
```

You can store these wherever or however you like, and you're only limited to the attributes available via LDAP. Then, you'd have to specify your LdapAuthoritiesProvider in the appropriate bean (ldapAuthoritiesPopulator, if memory serves).

I *believe* the above will work for non-AD LDAP, but you'll obviously need to test it to be sure. I recommend the [LDAP browser for Eclipse provided by Apache Studios](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), if you're not already using it.