# How do I implement a custom UserDetails object when authenticating against Active Directory via LDAP in Spring Security?

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

As in my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113115/how-do-i-use-a-custom-authorities-populator-with-spring-security-and-the-actived) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570222/how-to-authenticate-against-active-directory-via-ldap-over-tls), I continue to wade through the murky waters of integrating Spring Security into an existing application, which must ultimately authenticate against Active Directory via LDAP (over TLS), and populate the user's permissions based either on group membership or on a string stored in a custom AD field on the user object.

My current problem is that while I have successfully managed all of the above, I have *not* managed to get the User object with my custom permissions stored onto the session. This means that without additional work, every user will enjoy the permissions available to the most recently logged-in user.

I've worked around this issue by storing user permissions in a `Hashtable<username, permissions>` object, which I can secure by annotating its getters/setters with `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and principal.name == #username")`, but this is clearly not ideal. I'd much rather store the custom information gleaned from AD into the session as part of a custom user object. But how?

The relevant portions of my `security.xml` and `ldap.xml` configurations are as follows, respectively:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider"
            class="my.project.package.OverrideActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">


        <constructor-arg value="test.server"/>
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.0.2:389"/>
        <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

One of the problems I have foreseen is that when the `loadUserAuthorities()` method (overridden for my custom use of AD fiels) is called, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns `null`. This is a problem -- it indicates (to me, as I understand Spring's handling of sessions) that the authentication process has not completed, and the session ID pertaining to the to-be-authenticated user has not been generated. That is, Spring clears the anonymous session upon authentication in favor of a new session ID, but that session is apparently unavailable when `loadUserAuthorities()` is run.

So what shall I do? As I said, my hack works, and it seems to be secure (provided the right annotation), but it is hardly ideal. How *can* I properly store my custom user information onto a session-scoped user object while *also* maintaining authentication against AD via LDAP (over TLS)?

As always, I love and appreciate all the help I receive from the SO community.

Comment: Well since you use your own AuthenticationProvider, you need to create the AuthenticationToken yourself. Since I didn't implement LDAP authentication myself yet I can not help to much. But I guess it would be helpful for others if you post the your authenticationProvider. (On a sidenote I would imagine spring security ships with a build in LdapAuthenticationProvider? You could try that one for a reference.)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer this one?